# What is the correct term/expression for libraries' acquisition of books etc, as determined by the users?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, terminology

When libraries' decide what books etc they are to add to their collections, they look at, among other things, what people want to borrow, right? Now I'm wondering what the correct nominalisation for this is in English – I've thought about "user-determined acquisition", "user-controlled acquisition", and "user-dictated acquisition", but none of them generate any useful hits on Google. So, is there anyone who knows the established term/phrase here?

Thank you!

Comment: I know this sounds a little flippant, but in all seriousness, you should consider asking a reference librarian.

Comment: Wikipedia has an entry on [**patron-driven acquisition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patron-driven_acquisition) and notes that it also has the alternate name **demand-driven acquisition**.

Comment: @Juhasz Haha, yeah, that seems like the obvious solution, doesn't it :) Problem is, librarians in my country don't really know the term in English, only in our language... I guess I could have mailed a library in the UK though... if Canadian Yankee hadn't solved the problem :)

Comment: @CanadianYankee That's perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: The terminology for art galleries, libraries, etc., anything having to do with arts and/or literature, is "curating," not "acquisition." Even if it weren't for a library, that activity would generally be called "procurement." However, the specific position title used by libraries for one who does what you describe is "curator," which is why the verb is always "curate" and the noun is "curating."

Comment: Obviously, a curator would take borrower demand into account, but aside from the rare suggestion box, there's no mechanism by which a curator knows what that is. Curators' professional expertise is books and what books a collection needs. Curators are hired by a head librarian or board to achieve a certain vision they have for the collection and so curate accordingly, any specific books flowing from lists or policies set forth by a head librarian or board, not borrowers' demands.

Comment: Why not borrowers' demands? Because, aside from there being no real mechanism for a curator knowing what those demands are at a library, a curator not being one who works directly with borrowers, there's also no need since, at least in the US, there's a massive inter-library loan system. Whenever a borrower wants a particular book that a library doesn't have in its collection, the librarian doesn't send a request to the curator to add it to the library's collection but instead uses that system to find one that does and gets it for the borrower on loan from their, usually within a day or two.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Perhaps it's different in different countries, since in my country, libraries do have a well-developed system for procuring books based on what the users want to see in the library, and we also have a specific term for this kind of procurement. Also, the link that CanadianYankee provided seems to suggest this exists in other countries too. Still, I very much appreciate your comments! :)